# Incorrect Package URL when Updating from 3.2.7 to 3.3.6

Tags: one-click-updates

I ugpraded from 3.1.1 to 3.2.6 which went absolutely fine after I had disabled the 'Remember me'. I then wanted to go to 3.3.6 and followed the same process of going to the 'Update Manager' and hitting the Update Now. But after updating it once, the Update Checker still was showing update to 3.3.6 which made no sense as there was no error.

So I did the update again and same issue. Nothing breaks but still see 'Update to 3.3.6' message. And then I checked the details on the Update Manager and saw the issue. The Update URL is pointing to the 3.2.6_to_3.2.7 Stable Patch Package even though the installed version is already 3.2.7. Since all I did was click the update button on the 3.1.1, I am wondering if is this some sort of bug? And is there any way I could resolve it without having to do a fresh 3.3.6 install?

[image: Incorrect Update Package URL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually download the update package from the following link

[Joomla_3.3.6-Stable-Update_Package.zip](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19823/161247/%4A%6F%6F%6D%6C%61%5F%33%2E%33%2E%36%2D%53%74%61%62%6C%65%2D%55%70%64%61%74%65%5F%50%61%63%6B%61%67%65%2E%7A%69%70)

Once done, install it as you would any other extension via the Extension Manager in the Joomla backend. Please remember to take a backup of your site (including the database) before you do anything just to be on the safe side.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lodder. I knew about that method but was hoping I could do it with the one click update and was wondering what was wrong here. 

Will give it a go and let you know if it goes well. 

Yep I have all the backups and am doing this first in the test site anyway. Thanks for the reminder though.

Comment: Tried the update package and it installed but got the error, 'Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!' which makes sense as we have 5.3.3 and are hoping to upgrade the PHP version soon. Might be the reason why that 'bug' with the URL. Still it would be better if there was some sort of warning either on the on click upgrade or the Extension Manager update as installing the upgrade crashes the site and gives that error. Still marking it as an answer since the process is correct. Thanks.